# Writing onClick() event for an android custom dialog button

Tags: android, dialog, onclick

I have a button with id "ok" in my dialog.

**Partial - Dialog Layout:**

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/licenseTypeLayout">

        <Button
                android:id="@+id/ok"
                style="@style/agreement_text"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"                   
                android:text="Ok"/>        
    </LinearLayout>
```

**In activity:**

```
Dialog dialog;
    @OptionsItem(R.id.action_about)
    boolean displayPopup() {
        dialog = new Dialog(this);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.about_dialog);
        dialog.setTitle(R.string.app_name);          
        dialog.show();
        Button btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.ok);

        //btn remains empty

        return true;
    }
```

How would I write `onClick()` event for this button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To initialize the `Button`, you need to use the `Dialog` object

```
Button btn = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.ok);
```

Then set `OnClickListener` to the `Button` using `setOnClickListener()` as follows...

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {

        //write your code here
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I would guess you make the method:

public void closeDialog(View v){
   // Do what you want to do here (event handler)

}

?

Comment: To rephrase, are you suggesting me to change the method prototype?

Comment: not really sure what you mean, but whenever you put onClick="name" in your xml file the way you handle that event is with the method:

public void name(View v){ 
// Do what you want to do here (event handler)

}

You place that method in your activity class

Comment: Oh.. That was a typo. There is no onClick in the xml. Have edited the post